# gcc equivalent of VC++ warning C4018: signed/unsigned mismatch

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, warnings

Is there a gcc equivalent of VC++ warning C4018: signed/unsigned mismatch? We have an automated build on windows which runs with /WX and I'd like to be able to catch those warnings when building on Linux as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-Wsign-compare`

Comment: Unfortunately GCC warns in a lot of places where Visual Studio doesn't warn, so by enabling this warning I get a whole bunch of new warnings I have to fix.

Answer (score -2):

Best practice is to compile with `-Wall` it gives you most of warnings you need.

```
g++ -c -Wall code.cpp -o code.o
```

That what is done in **most** of projects and in fact it enables the warning you wanted.

Comment: you forgot -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow

Comment: In my version of gcc (4.8.5), `-Wall` does **not** enable `-Wsign-compare`